# how to retrieve the list of pending invoices

Tags: module, invoice

I am currently developping a module which to create email recovery for customers who have not paid.

I wanted to know what is the method to get the list of invoices awaiting a specific mode of payment such as payement order.

i think this method is in the class : Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice.

thank you for your help

Comment: look through the collection of orders `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` for which the status isn't `complete` or `new` (depending on what payment methods are available to your site)

Comment: I'm french too.can to write in french in this forum with you?

Comment: how you define an invoice is pending???

Comment: I'm pretty sure what he means by pending invoice is an order pending payment.
@strauss unfortunately, for the sake of readability by everyone, we can not talk French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be just like any other collection I assume:

```
$invoices = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection();
$invoices->addAttributeToSelect('state');
// 1 = "open", 2 = "paid", 3 = "cancelled"    
$invoices->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('eq' => 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();

foreach($orders as $order){

 if ($order->getBaseTotalDue() != 0){

   echo $order->getId().' is pending';
 }

}
```